# Hierarchical form and input

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, hierarchy

I have couple filters on my page and I would like some of the inputs to be hidden depending on the user selection.

For the example I have used region and country, If EMEA is selected, when submit is clicked I would like the second filter to offer only UK and France as possible options. However if France is submitted directly from the second filter I don't want to hide values on the Region filter.

So I am able to get the values of the Region filter but I don't how to use to filter the Countries...

HTML:

```
<div id="filter1">
<form action='#'>
<legend>Region</legend>
<input type="checkbox" value="all" class="select-all" checked>(All)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="americas" class="checkboxlistitem americas" checked>Americas<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="apac" class="checkboxlistitem apac" checked>APAC<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="emea" class="checkboxlistitem emea" checked>EMEA<br>
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form> 
</div>

<div id="filter2">
<form action='#'>
<legend>Country</legend>
<input type="checkbox" value="all" class="select-all" checked>(All)<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="us" class="checkboxlistitem americas" checked>US<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="uk" class="checkboxlistitem emea" checked>UK<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="india" class="checkboxlistitem apac" checked>India<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="france" class="checkboxlistitem emea" checked>France<br>
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Hide none relevant items
$("[type='submit']").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var checkedValue = $("[type='checkbox']:checked", $(this).parent()).map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get(); //
var filterName = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
alert(checkedValue);
alert(filterName);
});
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/Max06270/jutx6snm/

Thanks in advance, Max

Comment: Is there a reason you have two separate forms instead of combining the fields?

Comment: Yes, I use them as filters. The prod page contains 10 of them. When you click apply I use the values to send a request to an other app (Tableau Server)

Comment: I ask because I would suggest only submitting the values to the server at the end of the filter selection process to reduce the number of calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$("#region").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#filter1 input').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var checkbox = $("#filter2 input[region=" + value + "]");
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      checkbox.prop('checked', true).show();
      checkbox.closest('label').show();
    }else{
      checkbox.prop('checked', false).hide();
      checkbox.closest('label').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/jutx6snm/11/